# Custom sections on beamer aren't hyperlinked

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm working on a beamer document where I have a bunch of examples. I wrote a couple of macros that automatically add a frame title with "Example #", and also adds those frames to the table of contents for navigational ease. However, those "Example #" aren't hyperlinked to their respective frames on the toc, but they're correctly linked if I reference them elsewhere in the document. Here's my MWE code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,
hyperref={
%bookmarks=true,
linktocpage=true,
linktoc=all,
implicit=true,
%hypertexnames=false,
%debug
final=true
%
},
    handout
    ]{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish.noindentfirst,shorthands=off]{babel}
    \accentedoperators
    \decimalpoint

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \leavevmode\hbox{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}
    [wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\inserttitle: ~\insertsubtitle\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}
    [wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\mode<handout>{\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{mygreen}$\blacktriangleright$}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=mygreen}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\def\subsubsectionname{Example}
\newcounter{ejc}
\newcommand{\ExFr}[1][\empty]{
    \refstepcounter{ejc}
    \phantomsection
    \label{#1}
    \frametitle{Example ~\theejc}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\quad Example ~\theejc\\}}
\newcommand{\ExFrC}{
    \frametitle{Example ~\theejc}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{ejc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \colorlet{mygreen}{green!16!gray}

\title{A}
\subtitle{B}
\date{}

\setcounter{ejc}{16}

\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
 
\section*{Contents}

\begin{frame}<beamer:0>%On handout only
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}\tableofcontents[sections={2-}]\end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    %\tableofcontents[sections={2-4}]
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Math}

\begin{frame}
\ExFr[arbpar]%
$1+1=2$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\ExFrC
Also $1+2=3$.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Wow.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\ExFr
Remember example \ref{arbpar}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So the last `\ref` provides a clickable hyperlink to the corresponding frame but I can't get the toc to do that. As you can see I've been messing around with a bunch of options, nothing seems to work though. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link when you add your exercises to the toc like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish.noindentfirst,shorthands=off]{babel}
    \accentedoperators
    \decimalpoint

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \leavevmode\hbox{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}
    [wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\inserttitle: ~\insertsubtitle\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}
    [wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\mode<handout>{\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{mygreen}$\blacktriangleright$}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=mygreen}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\def\subsubsectionname{Example}
\newcounter{ejc}
\newcommand{\ExFr}[1][\empty]{
    \refstepcounter{ejc}
    \phantomsection
    \label{exercise-\theejc}
    \label{#1}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\quad\hyperlink{exercise-\theejc}{Example ~\theejc}\\}
  \frametitle{Example ~\theejc}
}

\newcommand{\ExFrC}{
    \frametitle{Example ~\theejc}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{ejc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \colorlet{mygreen}{green!16!gray}

\title{A}
\subtitle{B}
\date{}

\setcounter{ejc}{16}

\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
 
\section*{Contents}

\begin{frame}<beamer:0>%On handout only
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}\tableofcontents[sections={2-}]\end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    %\tableofcontents[sections={2-4}]
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Math}

\begin{frame}
\ExFr[arbpar]%
$1+1=2$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\ExFrC
Also $1+2=3$.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Wow.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\ExFr
Remember example \ref{arbpar}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```